# MYSQL select multi GROUP_CONCAT records

Tags: mysql

I am using an multi SQL queries to collect text records from a table and GROUP_CONCAT all in one record.
now! each query working file alone, but I need to create only one multi column query contain all sub-queries data

| name_list | id_list | model_list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaaaaaaa | 11111 | model1 |
| bbbbbbb | 22222 | model2 |

QUERY-1

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tmp_tbl.name SEPARATOR'\n') AS name_list
    FROM(
        (SELECT DISTINCT  owner_name AS name FROM t_vehicle_licen)
        UNION 
        (SELECT DISTINCT  user_name FROM t_vehicle_licen)
    ) AS tmp_tbl;
```

QUERY-2

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tmp_tbl.oid SEPARATOR'\n') AS id_list
    FROM(
        (SELECT DISTINCT  owner_id AS oid FROM t_vehicle_licen)
        UNION 
        (SELECT DISTINCT  user_id FROM t_vehicle_licen)
    ) AS tmp_tbl;
```

QUERY-3

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tmp_tbl.modl SEPARATOR'\n') AS model_list
    FROM(
        (SELECT DISTINCT  model AS modl FROM t_vehicle_licen)
    ) AS tmp_tbl;
```

Comment: add the expected result to understand your ask much better

Answer (score 0):

You could use one select union for all the columns:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tmp_tbl.name SEPARATOR'\n') AS name_list
 , GROUP_CONCAT(tmp_tbl.oid SEPARATOR'\n') AS id_list
 , GROUP_CONCAT(tmp_tbl.modl SEPARATOR'\n') AS model_list
from (
    SELECT  owner_name AS name,  owner_id AS oid, model AS modl FROM t_vehicle_licen
    UNION 
    SELECT  user_name, user_id, model 
    FROM t_vehicle_licen
    ) tmp_tbl
```

Using UNION you don't need a select distinct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
but it returns duplicated values when I need only unique values
I am using this record to feed combo box list and I don't want

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample and the expected  result as tabular text ..  ( UNION  don't return duplicated  values this mean that  your comment is not clear.. show also the original data not only the rsult)